# UITableViewController - Fixed Background Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to fix the position of a UITableViewController background image?

I've added the background image via the viewdidload method with the following code -

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blurredBGW"]];
```

But as the table is fairly long (and also contains static cells if that matters) it scrolls (and repeats) as you scroll down the table.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can try to add the background image as UIView and not as UIColor, try this:

```
 self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"blurredBGW.png"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

for swift version 3.0.try this code.it will set a fixed background to a table view  controller

```
 self.tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];

self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the background of your table (and the cells) transparent, and set the image for the view underneath the table.

Answer (score 0):

for

> swift 2.2

you may use the following line of code

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "xxxx.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to configure background with creating its specific xib, because background can be difficult. I do next:

1) Create a class, that helps me to load nib

```
class UIXIBView: UIView {

    var view: UIView!


    func setupXIBWithName(_ nibName: String) {
        view = self.getViewFromNibWithName(nibName)
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    }

    func getViewFromNibWithName(_ nibName: String) -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle.main
        let views = bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)! as [AnyObject]
        let view = views[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupXIBWithName(String(describing: type(of: self)))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupXIBWithName(String(describing: type(of: self)))
    }
}
```

2) I create your specific view, for example let it be **LKBackgroundView.swift**, and inherit it from UIXIBView

```
class LKBackgroundView: UIXIBView {
    // You can add your own logic there or override smth
}
```

3) I create xib with the same name **LKBackgroundView.xib**

4) I set FileOwner's class to LKBackgroundView inside xib, don't make a mistake by setting LKBackgroundView to the view class

5) Configure you xib like you want

6) Initialize your view inside ViewDidLoad inside your View Controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    LKBackgroundView(frame:tableView.bounds)
    tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

7) Test it

Answer (score 0):

## Xamarin/C# Solution

```
TableView.BackgroundView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("blurredBGW"))
```